# Google Maps API v3 – filtering markers using checkboxes (multiple tags per marker)

Tags: google-maps

I've built some filtering for a Google Map (v3 API) which is working with the code below but I want to expand on this. Some markers have multiple 'tags' assigned to them (and not just one) so if one of the checkboxes is turned off, and the marker has one of those tags, it should remain visible unless all it's tags are turned off.

An example of a marker's filter type could be

```
filter: {type: "1036|1102"}
```

or

```
filter: {type: "1033"}
```

Any below is an example of how the filters look and the JS.

```
<div class="filters">
    <ul class="tags">
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="1036" checked="checked" />Film</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="1102" checked="checked" />Heritage</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="1038" checked="checked" />Music</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="1075" checked="checked" />Shops</label></li>
    </ul>
</div>

var $filters = $('.map__container .filters ul.tags li input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {

    var $this = $(this),
        tag = $this.data('tag'),
        bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(),
        values = [];

    $filters.each(function(i, elem) {
        var value;
        value = elem.checked && elem.value;
        if (value) {
            values.push(value);
        }
    });

     var filterValue = values.join('|');

     //console.log(filterValue);

     $.each(map.markers, function (i, marker) {
         if (marker.filter.type.indexOf(filterValue) > -1) {
             marker.setVisible(true);
             //console.log('true:' + marker.filter.type);
         } else {
             marker.setVisible(false);
             //console.log('false:' + marker.filter.type);
         }
     });

});
```

Comment: Are you still encountering problems with this? Could you possibly create a self contained example that shows the other parts of your code? Maybe a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/) or a [jsfiddle](jsfiddle.net) sample would greatly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var $filters = $('.map__container .filters ul.tags li input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {

        var $this = $(this),
            bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(),
            values = [];

        $filters.each(function(i, elem) {
            var value;
            value = elem.checked && elem.value;
            if (value) {
                values.push(value);
            }
        });

         var filterValue = values;

         console.log(filterValue);

         $.each(map.markers, function (i, marker) {

             var tags = marker.filter.type.split("|");

             $.each(tags, function(i, tag) {

                 if (filterValue.includes(tag)) {
                     marker.setVisible(true);
                     console.log('true:' + tag);
                     return false;
                 } else {
                     marker.setVisible(false);
                     console.log('false:' + tag);
                 }

             });


         });

    });
```